# How to make a PL/SQL stored procedure display a table?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

Lets say I have a table called student that has 3 attributes, the student number, name and the favorite color and when i call the procedure like this:

```
execute favColor('RED');
```

the output should be:

```
NAME     FAV_COLOR 
-------- -----------
MARY     RED
JANE     RED
PETER    RED
JOHN     RED
```

Can I have an example code to do this? So far I only see procedures inserting or updating records and if there is a select statement in the procedure, it must have an into clause, does that mean it is impossible for procedures to display this output?

Comment: This is a trivial SQL SELECT.  Why do you need to do it within PL/SQL?  If you must do it in pl/sql then you simply put your SELECT in a cursor loop, fetching each row into an appropropriate local variable, and after each iteration, use dbms_output.put_line to show the results.  However, you also need to be aware that all PL/SQL executes inside the database.  dbms_output simply writes to a buffer, and it is up to the client to decide if it will read,process, and display that buffer.  Therefore, use of dbms_output is not really suitable for 'production' code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I don't have your table, I'll use Scott's with jobs instead of colors.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select ename, job from emp order by job, ename;

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
FORD       ANALYST
SCOTT      ANALYST
ADAMS      CLERK
JAMES      CLERK
MILLER     CLERK
SMITH      CLERK
BLAKE      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER
JONES      MANAGER
KING       PRESIDENT
ALLEN      SALESMAN
MARTIN     SALESMAN
TURNER     SALESMAN
WARD       SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

Procedure will return employees who have certain job:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure favJob (par_job in varchar2, par_rc out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    open par_rc for
  5      select ename, job
  6      from emp
  7      where job = par_job
  8      order by ename;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec favJob('MANAGER', :rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
BLAKE      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER
JONES      MANAGER

SQL>
```